# scalaquery conversion

Tags: scala, scalaquery

I have a query which gives a result as

```
org.scalaquery.ql.Query[(java.lang.String, Int, java.lang.String)]
```

What I need to do is to convert above query to a data list as follows

```
List[(String,Int,String)]
```

please give me a way to do this conversion in scalaquery.

Answer (score 1):

Once you define your query, you can simply call list on it, within a session:

```
val q = for (e <- Entities) yield e.*
db.withSession { session: Session => q.list()(session) }
```

See the docs for more info: https://github.com/szeiger/scala-query/wiki/Queries